# activation of customer by sending link to his email using Suitelet Scripts

Tags: netsuite

**Overview:**

I create one **custom customer form using Suitelet Script** with fields like name,email,phone in GET Method and the values entered in this fields obtained in the POST Method by request.getParameter() method. the customer record is created is successfully but when **clicking the submit button the customer record is to be "inactive" mode and the url link is to sent to the customer email address ,when he clicks the link his record is to be changed to"active" mode this must be with in same suitelet page.**

**My Requirement:**

I created the customer record successfully with INACTIVE MODE and link this send the customer mail but i need how to make the customer record to ACTIVE MODE when he clicks the link and the result is to be viewed in same suitelet page.

I have Given my code Sample Below:

```js
function getCustomerInfo(request, response){
       if(request.getMethod() == 'GET'){
        //CREATING THE CUSTOM FORM AND ADDING FIELDS IN THE FORM
        var form = nlapiCreateForm('Custom Customer Form');
           form.addField('sfg_company', 'text', 'Company Name').setMandatory(true);
           form.addField('sfg_address1','text','Address1');
           form.addField('sfg_address2','text','Address2');
           form.addField('sfg_city','text','City');
           form.addField('sfg_state','text','State');
           form.addField('sfg_emailaddr','email','Email').setMandatory(true);
           form.addField('sfg_phone','phone','Phone');
           form.addSubmitButton('Submit');
           response.writePage(form);
           
        }else{
         nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','form',form);
         // CREATING THE RECORD BY GETTING THE VALUES ENTERED IN THE CUSTOM FORM
          var compName = request.getParameter('sfg_company');
             var compAdd1 = request.getParameter('sfg_address1');    
             var compAdd2 = request.getParameter('sfg_address2');   
             var cities = request.getParameter('sfg_city');
             var stateName =request.getParameter('sfg_state');
             var email_addr = request.getParameter('sfg_emailaddr');
             var phone_num  = request.getParameter('sfg_phone');
             var newCust = nlapiCreateRecord('customer');
             newCust.setFieldValue('companyname', compName);
             newCust.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'addr1', 1, compAdd1);
             newCust.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'addr2', 1, compAdd2);
             newCust.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'city', 1, cities);
             newCust.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'state', 1, stateName);
             newCust.setFieldValue('email', email_addr);
             newCust.setFieldValue('phone', phone_num);
             newCust.setFieldValue('subsidiary', 1);
             newCust.setFieldValue('isinactive','T');
             //sending activation link to the customer
             var sender = nlapiGetUser();
             var receiver =  email_addr;
             var subject = 'Customer Activation Link';
             var recordId = nlapiGetRecordId();
             var url = "https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/common/entity/custjob.nl?id="+recordId+"&whence=";
             var body = 'Dear Customer,Your Record is Created Successfully and it will activated by click the following link :'+ url;
             nlapiSendEmail(sender,receiver,subject,body);
             var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(newCust);
             nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD','customer',id,null,false);
         
        }
         
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you basically want is to send out a confirmation link to a customer that they can click and complete some sort of registration.

If you want to re-use your suitele code then you need to pass a custom stage or action parameter that you can trigger different actions from. e.g.:

```
var stage = request.getParameter('custparam_action') || 'showForm';
switch(stage){
  case 'showForm': doShowForm(request, response); break;
  case 'validate' : doValidate(request, response); break;
}...
```

Then the url you need to send out needs to reference the suitelet rather than the customer page in Netsuite:

```
var ctx = nlapiGetContext();
var url = nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET', ctx.getScriptId(), ctx.getDeploymentId(), true) +"&custparam_action=validate"+ getSecureValidationParams());
```

the function `getSecureValidationParams` should create some sort of time sensitive parameters including a hashed key. If the request passes validation then you would show whatever other form you want to show or redirect to or show a thank you page.

Comment: can you help me briefly i'm unable to link the logic related to my concept. I understood that i have use nlapiResolveURL() to obtain the results within same suitelet. Could you elaborate more to me for understanding clearly.

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from reviewing the idea behind  http/s being a stateless protocol and how that works. Keep in mind that the browser used for entering information on your form may not be the browser that opens when an embedded email link is clicked.  May not even be the same device. 

You might find it beneficial to work with these concepts and sketch a UML Sequence Diagram (just on paper). Once you understand the mechanics of your process from that perspective most of the coding should fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCustomerInfo(request, response){
    if(request.getParameter('custscript_sfg_custmer_param') != null){
        var value = request.getParameter('custscript_sfg_custmer_param')
        var loadRecord = nlapiLoadRecord('customer',value);
        loadRecord.setFieldValue('isinactive','F');
                loadRecord.setFieldValue('custentity_sfg_referredby',1);
        nlapiSubmitRecord(loadRecord);
        nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD','customer',value);
    }
    if(request.getParameter('custscript_sfg_custmer_param') == null){
        if(request.getMethod() == 'GET'){
               //CREATING THE CUSTOM FORM AND ADDING FIELDS IN THE FORM
               var form = nlapiCreateForm('Custom Customer Form');
               form.addField('sfg_company', 'text', 'Company Name').setMandatory(true);
               form.addField('sfg_address1','text','Address1');
               form.addField('sfg_address2','text','Address2');
               form.addField('sfg_city','text','City');
               form.addField('sfg_state','text','State');
               form.addField('sfg_emailaddr','email','Email').setMandatory(true);
               form.addField('sfg_phone','phone','Phone');
               form.addSubmitButton('Submit');
               response.writePage(form);        
    }
   }
    if(request.getMethod() == 'POST'){
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','form',form);
        // CREATING THE RECORD BY GETTING THE VALUES ENTERED IN THE CUSTOM FORM
         var compName = request.getParameter('sfg_company');
         var compAdd1 = request.getParameter('sfg_address1');    
         var compAdd2 = request.getParameter('sfg_address2');   
         var cities = request.getParameter('sfg_city');
         var stateName =request.getParameter('sfg_state');
         var email_addr = request.getParameter('sfg_emailaddr');
         var phone_num  = request.getParameter('sfg_phone');
         var newCust = nlapiCreateRecord('customer');
         newCust.setFieldValue('companyname', compName);
         newCust.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'addr1', 1, compAdd1);
         newCust.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'addr2', 1, compAdd2);
         newCust.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'city', 1, cities);
         newCust.setLineItemValue('addressbook', 'state', 1, stateName);
         newCust.setFieldValue('email', email_addr);
         newCust.setFieldValue('phone', phone_num);
         newCust.setFieldValue('subsidiary', 1);
         newCust.setFieldValue('isinactive','T');
         //sending activation link to the customer
         var sender = nlapiGetUser();
         var receiver =  email_addr;
         var subject = 'Customer Activation Link';
         var recordId = nlapiGetRecordId();
         var webAddress = "https://system.na1.netsuite.com"
         var scriptType = nlapiGetContext().getScriptId();
         var scriptId = nlapiGetContext().getDeploymentId();
         var location = nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET',scriptType,scriptId);
         var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(newCust);
         var link = webAddress+location+'&custscript_sfg_custmer_param='+id+"&whence=";
         var url = '<a href="'+link+'">Click Here </a>';
         var body = 'Dear Customer,Your Record is Created Successfully and it will activated by click the following link :'+ url;
         nlapiSendEmail(sender,receiver,subject,body);
         nlapiSetRedirectURL('SUITELET',scriptType,scriptId);

    }
```

**The above code will Get Customer Information through external Suitelet form and saving the record in the system.**

Comment: It is likely you are going to run into issues if you run that code outside a logged in Netsuite session. If you are running this successfully on a public link would you mind sharing the role and audience settings of the script deployment?